# Julia loops are as slow as R loops

Tags: r, performance, loops, julia

The code below in Julia and R is to show that the estimator of the population variance is a biased estimator, that is it depends on the sample size and no matter how many times we average over different observations, for small number of data points it is not equal to the variance of the population.

It takes for Julia ~10 seconds to finish the two loops and R does it in ~7 seconds.
If I leave the code inside the loops commented then the loops in R and Julia take the same time and if I only sum the iterators by `s = s + i+ j` Julia finishes in ~0.15s and R in ~0.5s.

Is it that Julia loops are slow or R became fast?
How can I improve the speed of the code below for Julia?
Can the R code become faster?

**Julia:**

```
using Plots
trials = 100000
sample_size = 10;
sd = Array{Float64}(trials,sample_size-1)

tic()
for i = 2:sample_size
    for j = 1:trials
        res = randn(i)
        sd[j,i-1] = (1/(i))*(sum(res.^2))-(1/((i)*i))*(sum(res)*sum(res))
    end
end
toc()
sd2 = mean(sd,1)
plot(sd2[1:end])
```

**R:**

```
trials = 100000
sample_size = 10
sd = matrix(, nrow = trials, ncol = sample_size-1)
start_time = Sys.time()
for(i in 2:sample_size){
  for(j in 1:trials){
  res <- rnorm(n = i, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  sd[j,i-1] = (1/(i))*(sum(res*res))-(1/((i)*i))*(sum(res)*sum(res))

}
}

end_time = Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
sd2 = apply(sd,2,mean)
plot(sqrt(sd2))
```

The plot in case anybody is curious!:
[image]

One way I could achieve much higher speed is to use parallel loop which is ver easy to implement in Julia:

```
using Plots
trials = 100000
sample_size = 10;


sd = SharedArray{Float64}(trials,sample_size-1)

tic()
@parallel for i = 2:sample_size
    for j = 1:trials
        res = randn(i)
        sd[j,i-1] = (1/(i))*(sum(res.^2))-(1/((i)*i))*(sum(res)*sum(res))
    end
end
toc()
sd2 = mean(sd,1)
plot(sd2[1:end])
```

Comment: in `R` I would do: `my.sd <- function(i) {;
  res <- rnorm(n = i, mean = 0, sd = 1);
  mean(res*res) - mean(res)^2;
};
sd <- replicate(trials, sapply(2:sample_size, my.sd))`

Comment: After you wrap this in a function, you will see that almost the entire time is spent inside `randn`, it has nothing to do with the speed of loops in Julia vs R. You are also writing `sum(res)*sum(res)` instead of `sum(res)^2`, and `sum(res.^2)` instead of `sum(abs2, res)`, which are both wasting resources. You can rewrite to this: `sd[j, i-1] = sum(abs2, res) / i - (sum(res) / i)^2`.

Comment: @DNF, all this is correct but additionally in Julia also loops themselves when executed in global scope are slower than loops executed in a function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using global variables in Julia in general is slow and should give you speed comparable to R. You should wrap your code in a function to make it fast.

Here is a timing from my laptop (I cut out only the relevant part):

```
julia> function test()
           trials = 100000
           sample_size = 10;
           sd = Array{Float64}(trials,sample_size-1)

           tic()
           for i = 2:sample_size
               for j = 1:trials
                   res = randn(i)
                   sd[j,i-1] = (1/(i))*(sum(res.^2))-(1/((i)*i))*(sum(res)*sum(res))
               end
           end
           toc()
       end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test()
elapsed time: 0.243233887 seconds
0.243233887
```

Additionally in Julia if you use `randn!` instead of `randn` you can speed it up even more as you avoid reallocation of `res` vector (I am not doing other optimizations to the code as this optimization is distinct to Julia in comparison to R; all other possible speedups in this code would help Julia and R in a similar way):

```
julia> function test2()
           trials = 100000
           sample_size = 10;
           sd = Array{Float64}(trials,sample_size-1)

           tic()
           for i = 2:sample_size
               res = zeros(i)
               for j = 1:trials
                   randn!(res)
                   sd[j,i-1] = (1/(i))*(sum(res.^2))-(1/((i)*i))*(sum(res)*sum(res))
               end
           end
           toc()
       end
test2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test2()
elapsed time: 0.154881137 seconds
0.154881137
```

Finally it is better to use `BenchmarkTools` package to measure execution time in Julia. First `tic` and `toc` functions will be removed from Julia 0.7. Second - you mix compilation and execution time if you use them (when running `test` function twice you will see that the time is reduced on the second run as Julia does not spend time compiling functions).

EDIT:

You can keep `trials`, `sample_size` and `sd` as global variables but then you should prefix them with `const`. Then it is enough to wrap a loop in a function like this:

```
const trials = 100000;
const sample_size = 10;
const sd = Array{Float64}(trials,sample_size-1);

function f()
    for i = 2:sample_size
        for j = 1:trials
            res = randn(i)
            sd[j,i-1] = (1/(i))*(sum(res.^2))-(1/((i)*i))*(sum(res)*sum(res))
        end
    end
end

tic()
f()
toc()
```

Now for `@parallel`:

First, you should use `@sync` before `@parallel` to make sure all works correctly (i.e. that all workers have finished before you move to the next instruction). To see why this is needed run the following code on a system with more than one worker:

```
sd = SharedArray{Float64}(10^6);
@parallel for i = 1:2
    if i < 2
        sd[i] = 1
    else
        for j in 2:10^6
            sd[j] = 1
        end
    end
end
minimum(sd) # most probably prints 0.0
sleep(1)
minimum(sd) # most probably prints 1.0
```

while this

```
sd = SharedArray{Float64}(10^6);
@sync @parallel for i = 1:2
    if i < 2
        sd[i] = 1
    else
        for j in 2:10^6
            sd[j] = 1
        end
    end
end
minimum(sd) # always prints 1.0
```

Second, the speed improvement is due to `@parallel` macro not `SharedArray`. If you try your code on Julia with one worker it is also faster. The reason, in short, is that @parallel internally wraps your code inside a function. You can check it by using `@macroexpand`:

```
julia> @macroexpand @sync @parallel for i = 2:sample_size
           for j = 1:trials
               res = randn(i)
               sd[j,i-1] = (1/(i))*(sum(res.^2))-(1/((i)*i))*(sum(res)*sum(res))
           end
       end
quote  # task.jl, line 301:
    (Base.sync_begin)() # task.jl, line 302:
    #19#v = (Base.Distributed.pfor)(begin  # distributed\macros.jl, line 172:
                function (#20#R, #21#lo::Base.Distributed.Int, #22#hi::Base.Distributed.Int) # distributed\macros.jl, line 173:
                    for i = #20#R[#21#lo:#22#hi] # distributed\macros.jl, line 174:
                        begin  # REPL[22], line 2:
                            for j = 1:trials # REPL[22], line 3:
                                res = randn(i) # REPL[22], line 4:
                                sd[j, i - 1] = (1 / i) * sum(res .^ 2) - (1 / (i * i)) * (sum(res) * sum(res))
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end, 2:sample_size) # task.jl, line 303:
    (Base.sync_end)() # task.jl, line 304:
    #19#v
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I use a shared array to do parallel computing the code becomes fast too (0.1s). Does this have anything to do with global variable apart from the fact that I am using six cores? Is it possible to define global variables in a better way rather than put the code inside the function?

Comment: Is there any references to explain why global variables make Julia faster?
Are there any risks with using global variables?

Comment: It is explained in the Julia Manual https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables-1. For `SharedArray` itself does not help here `@parallel` helps. I will improve my answer to cover this.

Comment: The start of the answer makes it sound like global variables make Julia faster, while the opposite is true. Perhaps clarify that. Also, if you move `randn!` outside the innermost loop, to work on a matrix, it can be multithreaded. Finally, the expression in the innermost loop is suboptimal (e.g. `sum(res)*sum(res)`.)

Comment: Thanks. I have written that then Julia has speed of R (so slow) - but I will clarify :). I did not do other optimizations because MOON wanted to compare the same codes on Julia and R (and not asking how to make fastest possible Julia code).

Comment: Thank you both! I learned a lot! If there are any points left (further optimization of Julia code etc. .) Please feel free to add to the answer!

Comment: I have updated the answer - it is long now, as you have asked about many topics in one question. I hope all is clear.